# How to prevent division by zero when the denominator is a CGFloat?

Tags: objective-c

I have a number which is a CGFloat and I want to divide it by some number. How can I make sure that the divisor is not equal to zero or NaN?

Comment: Perhaps compare it against zero and not divide by it if it is zero?

Comment: Its poor practise to use an equal comparison between floats as a conditional.

Comment: that's not a "one size fits all" rule. You have to think about *why.* In this case, it's perfectly fine to compare against zero.

Comment: You can use [`isnan(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/isnan.3.html) to check for NaNs.

Comment: Petur, it's bad practice to apply rules without thinking. Using an equal comparison against 0 is the one hundred percent guaranteed to work way to check whether a floating-point number is zero or not. And you can compare x == x to see if it's a NaN or not. So: if (x !=  0.0 && x == x) { /* Not 0 or NaN */ }

Comment: I think it's useful to think about what you want the result to be when the divisor is *close to* zero. Or what the limit of the result goes to as the divisor approaches zero. There's a good chance that you want to change the formula or skip the division significantly before the divisor actually reaches zero. Or perhaps you want to divide by (1 + some non-negative number) or the like.

Comment: And, to my knowledge, float divide-by-zero is not an exception but rather produces an Inf result, so you can always just do the operation and then check the result.

Comment: Hot Licks you are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example checks the divisor before the division to make sure it's not 0 or NaN.

```
CGFloat dividend = 5.f;
CGFloat divisor = 3.f;

if (! (isnan(divisor) || divisor == 0.f)){
    CGFloat quotient = dividend / divisor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
CGFloat number = 5 //declare the CGFloat
CGFloat divisor = 2 //where this equals whatever you want to divide by

if (divisor != 0 && !(isnan(divisor))){
 CGFloat answer = number / divisor;
}
```

Comment: It's just an example of how to check to see if it is zero.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to add pointers, but that was obviously not the point (no pun intended) of the answer.